# Angular ng-bind displaying 'object instead of value

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have an angular app where i am getting data from a service as follows:

```
angular.module('jsonService', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('MyService',function($http) {
        return {
            getItems: function(profileid,callback) {
                $http.get('/api/myapp/'+profileid+'/').success(callback);
            }
        };
    });
```

My controller app.js is as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'jsonService']);
    app.controller('mycontroller', function(MyService, $scope, $modal, $log, $http) {
        $scope.profileid=3619;

        MyService.getItems($scope.profileid,function(data){
            $scope.profiledata = data;
        });
    });
```

The json object i get in the data looks as follows:

```
[
    {
        "profile_id": 3619, 
        "student_id": "554940", 
        "first_name": "Samuel", 
        "last_name": "Haynes"
    }
]
```

When i am trying to display these values in a textbox, i do not the the value in it. Instead i get a `[object Object]` . This is how i am calling the ng-bind in the html doc:

```
<label for="sid">Student ID</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="profiledata" ng-bind="{{profiledata.student_id}}" />
```

How do i display the values from the json object?

Comment: can you add a plunker or fiddle?

Comment: When you use ng-bind you can remove "{{"

Comment: same thing even when i removed them!

Comment: Can you stringify the object before displaying it? If you are just wanting to show one property (after looking closer) you need to access it as an array.

Comment: It seems like `profiledata` is an array? if so try `profiledata[0].student_id`. If you want to display multiple records use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: @PSL i am getting just one record when i send the profile id to the service. profiledata[0].student_id gave me the same again!

Comment: What does 'the same again' mean? Make sure you are clearing your cache. Also, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @MikeCheel same again meaning the same [object Object] instead of the value. I also tried doing the JSONstringify. I did something like:      MyService.getItems($scope.profileid,function(data){
   $scope.pf = data;   
  });
  $scope.profiledata = JSON.stringify($scope.pf); ...... Buti didnt get any value :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this simplified jsbin I made: http://jsbin.com/korufi/1/

Change your input to:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="profiledata[0].student_id" />
```

ng-bind ends up making the input look like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control">554940</input>
```

which will not make the student id show up in the textbox. ng-model will.